# How can a 12V 80Ah Battery be 1800W? Shouldn't it be 960W?

Tags: batteries, watts, capacity

How can a 12V 80Ah Battery be 1800W? Shouldn't it be 960W?
I was looking for **12V 80Ah Deep Cycle Batteries** on Amazon and most of them were 1800W.
Like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Cycle-Battery-RENOGY-SOLAR-PANELS/dp/B0143K89KA/ref=sr_1_fkmrnull_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0143K89KA)

Comment: You're confusing A with Ah. Not the same thing.

Comment: Think of Ampere-Hours as way to measure _how long it will last if your circuit will draw X amount of amps_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

80Ah means "80 ampere*hours" -- **approximately**, the battery can give 80 amperes * 1 hour, or 160 amperes * 0.5 hours, or 40 amperes * 2 hours.

1800W refers to maximum power -- if you draw more than that, the battery may overheat and fail. At 12 volt, this means 150 amperes. This means that you should not discharge battery faster than that. Incidentally, this means the battery can be safely discharged in about 40 minutes.